# combine / include various PHP files into one single PHP file

Tags: php, file, include

Hello Friends I am a newbie programmer and very very new to PHP. I am seeking help in writing a small php Function. The situation is like this:

I am running Joomla and I have a template which is in BLOCKS for example:

```
header.php
topmodules.php
mainbody.php
bottommodules.php
footer.php
```

All my blocks are placed in a directory (/layouts/blocks). All these blocks need to be joined in the main Index.php file.

The function I know is something like this:

```
<?php
function get_header(){
  require_once(TEMPLATEPATH.'/layouts/blocks/header.php');
}
?>
```

And then call it like:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

But that is not very professional and also I will have to write a function for every file moreover this can also be accomplished by just using

```
<?php require(YOURBASEPATH . DS .'layouts'. DS .'blocks'. DS . "header.php"); ?>
```

But what I am looking for is to have a single function /class which can get that PHP file from that directory, just by passing the name of the file so that I can add some more blocks to that directory in future without re-writing the function and simply call them like:

```
<?php $this->getBlock('header') ?>
<?php $this->getBlock('topmodules') ?>
<?php $this->getBlock('mainbody') ?>
<?php $this->getBlock('bottommodules') ?>
<?php $this->getBlock('footer') ?>
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a parameter to the function you have:

```
function getBlock($filename){
  require_once(YOURBASEPATH . DS . 'layouts' .DS . 'blocks'. DS . $filename .'.php');
}
```

Comment: That did not work it gives a message:Fatal error: Call to undefined method JDocumentHTML::getBlock() in E:\xampp\htdocs\cms\templates\joomla_j15\index.php on line 11

Comment: @Vikram well, you will need to embed the function in the JDocumentHTML class if you want to use `$this->`

Comment: This is how I called that in my index.php <?php $this->getBlock('header') ?> and also tried <?php getBlock('header') ?> but both did not work.

Comment: @Vikram the latter should work, you need to define and call it just as you did for `get_header()`

Comment: Hmmm that is a bit latin and german to me. As I mentioned in my question I am very very new to programming and PHP both. Hence may I request you to elaborate a bit on the process?

Comment: @Vikram what happens if you call `getBlock("header")`? What error message comes up?

Comment: I used function getBlock($filename){
  require_once(YOURBASEPATH . DS . 'layouts' .DS . 'blocks'. DS . $filename .'.php');
} in my functions.php and this is how I called it in the index.php file <?php getBlock('header') ?> but no luck

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method JDocumentHTML::getBlock() in E:\xampp\htdocs\cms\templates\joomla_j15\index.php on line 11 and in line no. 11 of index.php I have this <?php getBlock('header') ?>

Comment: @Vikram there must be more to your code than you're showing currently, that error doesn't make sense. Maybe worth a separate question

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_header_improved($s){
  require_once(TEMPLATEPATH.'/layouts/blocks/' . $s . '.php');
}

<?php get_header_improved('header') ?>
<?php get_header_improved('topmodules') ?>
<?php get_header_improved('mainbody') ?>
<?php get_header_improved('bottommodules') ?>
<?php get_header_improved('footer') ?>
```

I not tried, but this should work.

Comment: Iused  function get_header_improved($s){ require_once(TEMPLATEPATH.'/layouts/blocks/' . $s . '.php');
 } in my functions.php and this is how I called it in the index.php file <?php get_header_improved('header') ?> but no luck.